# How to get the Bean package from ConfigurableApplicationContext

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-framework-beans

Using a interface like **ConfigurableApplicationContext**, it is possible to retrieve the list of Beans running in the **Spring DI container**, but I would like to know what Beans come from the User Space and what Beans comes from the Spring Boot / Spring Boot Starters.

```
@TestConfiguration
static class BeanInventoryConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext;

    record BeanInventory(List<String> beans) {}

    @Bean
    public BeanInventory getBeanInventory(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        String[] allBeanNames = applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames();
        return new BeanInventory(Arrays.stream(allBeanNames).toList());
    }
}
```

Does exist a way to return the package where the Bean is located?
If I know the package, I could filter in a easy way.

Reviewing the Javadoc from Spring, I didnt find a way:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ConfigurableApplicationContext.html

Many thanks in advance

POC: https://github.com/jabrena/spring-boot-http-client-poc/blob/main/src/test/java/ms/info/ms/BeanInventoryTests.java

Comment: Anything that isn't in an `org.springframework` package is probably yours. Or anything in `com.your.basepackage` is yours. You would need to get all the beans and not just the names for that (or maybe better the bean definitions, to prevent early instantiation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for it:

```
@TestConfiguration
public class BeanInventory {

    @Autowired
    private ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public record BeanInfo(String name, String pkg) {}
    private final List<BeanInfo> beans = new ArrayList<>();

    @PostConstruct
    private void after() {

        final String[] beanNames = applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames();
        for (String beanName : beanNames) {
            final Object beanObject = applicationContext.getBean(beanName);
            Class<?> targetClass = AopUtils.getTargetClass(beanObject);

            if (AopUtils.isJdkDynamicProxy(beanObject)) {
                Class<?>[] proxiedInterfaces = AopProxyUtils.proxiedUserInterfaces(beanObject);
                Assert.isTrue(proxiedInterfaces.length == 1, "Only one proxied interface expected");
                targetClass = proxiedInterfaces[0];
            }

            beans.add(new BeanInfo(beanName, targetClass.getPackageName()));
        }
    }

    public List<BeanInfo> getBeans() {
        return beans;
    }

}
```

Further information here:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/29973#event-8527246281

Note: Many thanks to Simon Basle